# Android: Using methods from an Activity in a Widget. Extend Activity and AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, extend, inheritance

I'm working on an Android app which has an activity and a widget.  This is currently implemented via two classes in two .java files - one for the activity (extending Activity), one for the widget (extending AppWidgetProvider).  Nothing out of the ordinary here as far as I'm aware...

However, the widget class code could be a lot simpler if it was to make use of functions and asynctasks defined in the activity class.  Duplicating these functions seems like bad design, so I'm wondering how I can structure the app to make them usable?

Can I extend both Activity and AppWidgetProvider somehow?  Can I import one in the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either make the funcs static, or make a 3rd class to hold these funcs

Answer (score 2):

Move the functions down into a service. Create a Service and you can use context.startService(Intent) from you WigetProvider or from the activity to access the functions.